# Angular2 SanitizationService provider

Tags: angular

I have an existing angular2 application and I am upgrading it to rc.0 from beta.  I have it compiling but at runtime I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for SanitizationService! (ViewUtils ->
>   SanitizationService)

I can't find much information on the sanitation service.  I don't see it being used in the quickstart.  I have no reference to sanitation in my code - it's only in the angular libraries.

Has anyone gotten this error?
How to I set a provider?

Comment: Why don't you get straight to rc.1? There shouldn't be anything to do to get the `SanizationService` working.

Comment: I had problems skipping releases so I was going to go to 0, then to 1 to minimize the changes.  In this case, I just change to rc1 and it works.  I'll just skip 0.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanitization service was introduced in rc.0 and it's likely that it contained more bugs than in the most recent version rc.1 therefore I suggest to skip rc.0 and go straight to rc.1